# Openstack Juju charms and Modified Kernels

Tags: juju, openstack

On a multi-node Kilo, on one of the nova-compute node, running 14.04, needed to modify the kernel, in order to install Intel's MSSR6. This seems to have gone well, i.e., MSS is activated, node is accessible through Horizon and VMs can be instantiated. However, nova-compute charm is constantly attempting to download header files for the newly created kernel, which doesn't have a standard upstream name:

```
$ uname -ar
Linux lab-gpu01 3.14.5MSSr6 #2 SMP Wed Jul 22 16:40:32 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The following is observed in juju log file:

```
...
2015-07-23 19:03:08 DEBUG worker.uniter.jujuc server.go:103 hook context id "nova-compute-gpu1/0:config-changed:7060013946773596029"; dir "/var/lib/juju/agents/unit-nova-compute-gpu1-0/charm"
2015-07-23 19:03:08 INFO juju-log Couldn't acquire DPKG lock. Will retry in 10 seconds.
2015-07-23 19:03:18 INFO config-changed Reading package lists...
2015-07-23 19:03:19 INFO config-changed Building dependency tree...
2015-07-23 19:03:19 INFO config-changed Reading state information...
2015-07-23 19:03:19 INFO config-changed E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-3.14.5MSSr6
2015-07-23 19:03:19 INFO config-changed E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-3.14.5MSSr6'
2015-07-23 19:03:19 INFO worker.uniter.jujuc server.go:102 running hook tool "juju-log" ["Couldn't acquire DPKG lock. Will retry in 10 seconds."]
...
```

Is it possible, through configuration, ask the charm not to try to install the kernel header files?
Cheers,

Answer (score 2):

There is no charm configuration option to control that.  When taking manual steps such as this to customize the unit, it will be necessary to manually resolve the issue.

It sounds like the custom kernel package is recommending the `linux-headers-3.14.5MSSr6` package.

Please see the `--no-install-recommends` option and other info in the [apt-get man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/man8/apt-get.8.html).